# WordPress custom url without parameters

Tags: wordpress

I have create a custom url for my plugin in WordPress that I don't like to have any argument.

Lets say that my URL us that

http://www.mysite.ext/test/

How can I know from my code that the users in on /test/ and not in any other page from within my code ?

This is my code:

```
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rule');

function add_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('test/?', 'index.php', 'top');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you only want to test whether the current pages ends with /test/, can you do it in php like this:

```
//get host name, this returns www.mysite.ext
host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
//get full path, this returns /test
$script = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

This is not test, but worth trying.